# How to select a a pattern from notepad++ or any other text editor?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I just backed up my sql database and have got data like:

[image: db_image]

I just want user:pass and want to remove the data after it
Like I want "@*> deleted, * is the any data between "@ and >

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want and why. Sounds like you might want to use a regex

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the text matching the regular expression `"@.*>` with nothing.

Ctrl-F to open the find dialog.

Navigate to the "Replace" tab.

Insert `"@.*>` into the "Find what:" input dialog, "Replace with:" should be empty.

Make sure "Search Mode" is set to "Regular expression" and that ". matches newline" it not ticked.

It should look like this:

[image]

Then try to replace one or two entries, and when you're confindent that it works press "Replace All".